# kpss test in eviews

Tags: time-series, econometrics, eviews, kpss-test

I am taking 5% critical values for adf pp and za. In kpss test critical value is passing from 1% but not from 5% so

[image]

is it stationary or not also when take differences of series first and second still not under the critical value of 5%

Answer (score 1):

You are rejecting the null at 5% sig level, not stationary.

Answer (score 0):

"You are rejecting the null at 5% sig level, not stationary."

This is rather curious! Can the KPSS test result as above be accepted for 1% significant level but not at 5% significant level?